# Remove leading dash from a string

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have this:

```
-asdfj-
-jhbjbhk---kjn
klsjdn-kad-.d-.--.-ask-n-
-sd-kasd-ksjd-nkasjd
```

I need this:

```
asdfj-
jhbjbhk---kjn
klsjdn-kad-.d-.--.-ask-n-
sd-kasd-ksjd-nkasjd
```

Whenever I have a dash in the first place of the string, I want it to be deleted and whatever is at the second position should take its place (i.e. the first place).

Answer (score 4):

You can use `LTRIM`or `TRIM` string functions:

e.g:

```
SELECT LTRIM(column_name, '-') FROM table_name;
```

```
SELECT TRIM(LEADING '-' FROM column_name) FROM table_name;
```

You can find the interactive code, with example data: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/28e115/6

For more details refer:

- https://w3resource.com/PostgreSQL/trim-function.php
- https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html

Answer (score 2):

You can use `regexp_replace()` for that:

```
select regexp_replace(the_column, '^-', '')
from the_table;
```

The regular expression `'^-'` means exactly one `-` at the beginning of the string.

---

If you want to change the data in the table permanently, you can use that in an UPDATE statement:

```
update the_table
    set the_column = regexp_replace(the_column, '^-', '');
where the_column ~ '^-';
```

The `where` clause makes sure only those rows are updated where something is changed.